# R beginning match count

Tags: regex, r

I am using R and have the following string below:

```
s <- "\t\t\t   \t\t\thello    world   !  \t\t\thello"
```

I want to get the match count of whitespaces at the start of the string only, not anywhere else. So the spaces between the content should be ignored and only the start should be counted. The result would be "9" here.

I have tried the following but it only returns a count of "1" ...

```
sapply(regmatches(s, gregexpr('^(\\s)', s)), length)
```

I am not very good at regex, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For matching the first occurrence, `regexpr()` would be more appropriate than `gregexpr()`. As a result of that switch, `sapply()` will no longer be necessary because `regexpr()` returns an atomic vector whereas `gregexpr()` returns a list.

You could use the following regular expression, looking at the *match.length* attribute from the result of `regexpr()`.

```
attr(regexpr("^\\s+", s), "match.length")
# [1] 9
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

- `^` Force the regex to be at the beginning of the string.
- `\\s` Space characters: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, and space.
- `+` The preceding item will be matched one or more times.

Reference: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing

Comment: `attr(regexpr("^\\s+",s),"match.length")` works too.

Comment: @thelatemail - Interesting.  So a tab `\\t` is recognized as a regular space? I didn't know that

Comment: I think `\\s` is equivalent to `[[:space:]]`, which is "*Space characters: tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters.*" - see `?regex`

Comment: Ok I've edited.  That makes more sense in the context of *whitespace*

Comment: @RichardScriven i suggest you to turn `"^\\s+"` to `"^\\h+"` because `^\\s+` counts a newline character which was present at the start. I think op means only the horizontal spaces not the vertical ones..

Comment: `\\h` horizontal spaces and you need to turn on perl mode. I think you could use `[[:blank:]]` to do the same as `\h`

Comment: Oh okay.  I had `[[:blank:]]` originally then I changed it to `\\s` haha

Comment: All the visible spaces are horizontal spaces that is a space or tab.. Vertical spaces includes `\n`, `\r`, `\f`

Comment: if you have any doubt, change your input string to this `s <- "\n"` and then try..

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can solve this is anchoring with `\G`. The `\G` feature is an anchor that can match at one of two positions; the beginning of the string, or the point where the last character of last match is consumed.

```
sapply(gregexpr("\\G\\s", s, perl = TRUE), length)
# [1] 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this also.

```
> sapply(gregexpr("[^\\h].*(*SKIP)(*F)|\\h", s, perl = TRUE), length)
[1] 9
> sapply(gregexpr("\\S.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\\h", s, perl = TRUE), length)
[1] 9
```

`\\h` matches the horizontal spaces. `\S` matches a non-space character and the following `.*` matches all the characters following that non-space character upto the line end. `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to fail. And the part next to the `|` that is, `\h` matches all the remaining horizontal spaces (ie, the spaces which are present at the start.)